# Android - Creating read/write text file included with app files

Tags: android, file

I am new to Android development and I am trying to make an app which reads from a text file which only holds a float. When using the app you change that float's value and when you close the app that value is stored in the text file. My question is: is it possible to create that file before running the app? If so, where should I place it? Tried using assets but realized it is read only. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use SharedPreferences.
Here is a good Tutorial for u.
Its really easy to use. Just give the variable a key and save it.
If you need it, ask with the key for the variable :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UC2wAuxECw0

Comment: I know SharedPreferences but I need it to stay in memory when the app is closed/destroyed

Comment: That is what SharedPreferences does :D

Comment: XxGoliathusxX Lol! Didn't know! I thought they were deleted when the app closed. Thanks :)